# How to write c++ functions by returning parameters?

Tags: c++

Need help in figuring out how to write function and returning parameters. Wrote the question below and answer from solution manual, not sure how to write the function though very confused :(

Here's what I've tried:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
char Answer; 

void max(); 

void main () { 
    int max(int num1, int num2) { 
        if (num1 > num2) 
            return num1; 
        else 
            return num2; 
    } 

    print(); 
    system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: oops no nb3 sorry only nb2 and nb1

Comment: C++ doesn't allow nested functions. It's an extension of whatever compiler you are using if your code compiles. Also, if you get errors compiling you should add them to the question, preferably verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems with the question. In the answer you gave there are 3 parameters (int nb1,nb2, nb3) but the question says there are two. Also there should be an int before each identifier if this is C++, is this C++? Also it's not specified what to do if the parameters are equal (e.g. max(6, 6)) though presumably this isn't important. Here's what I'd do:

```
int max(int nb1, int nb2)
{
 if(b1 > b2)//this could be b1 >= b2, I think that's what your solution manual has
    return b1;
 else
    return b2;
}
```

---

EDIT in response to comment:

Given what you have done so far this is what I would change to get things to work. The following has somethings you should try to avoid

1. int main() and return 0 should be used instead of void main()
2. system("pause") should not be used instead you could wait for a user to press enter

But it seems like you have enough to get your head around without the above two concerns :-)
You had the function print you should use cout << "text goes here" << endl; when programing in C++ (C uses printf). I'm guessing your hard-coding the input so set the values of num1 and num2 to whichever two numbers to be compared.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int max(int nb1, int nb2)
{
        if(nb1 > nb2)
                return nb1;
        else
                return nb2; 
}

void main()
{
        int num1 = 6;//put one number to be compared here
        int num2 = 8;//put second number to be compared here
        int result = max(num1, num2)
        cout << result << endl;
        system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: so if i wanted to input the values like asking it to do cout<<"enter your first\n"; numbercin<<num1; cout<<"enter second number

Comment: etc... where would i put that after int result=max(num1,num2) ??

Comment: Edit your original question with the code, it's too hard to follow down here. Use proper formatting by clicking on the code tag of the WYSIWYG editor. I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying...but I think you're on the right track. Basically `cout` is for displaying text and `cin` is for getting user input from the keyboard.